# Inserting a newline near the end of a std::string

Tags: c++, string, insert, newline, std

I'm struggling with trying to implement a C++ code solution that will allow me to insert a newline (i.e. a string literal `'\n'`) *towards the end* of a `std::string`, and **not** at the very end as most implementations show.

For example, I want to insert a `'\n'` just `-1` characters before the very end itself. So if the string was 100 characters long (poor analogy I know), then I'd like to insert the string literal at the 99th character in a clean, easily readable manner.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [this `std::string` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) could be of help? It should at least tell that there's a function ti *insert* characters into a string at an arbitrary (but valid) position.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
std::string test{"abcdef"};

if (!test.empty())
   test.insert(test.length() - 1, "\n");
```

and here's one based on iterators:

```
if (!test.empty())
   test.insert(std::prev(test.end()), '\n');
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, none of the examples were near that simple.